# How to save an excel file and attach it to new object?

Tags: python, django, excel, xlwt

I have a django project and I've created an excel file using xlwt(end snippet of file generation).

```
export_wb.save(output)
output.seek(0)
response = HttpResponse(output.getvalue())
response['Content-Type'] = 'application/vnd.ms-excel'
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename='+filename
return response
```

Now in my view I want to generate this file and attach it to a new object and save it, so I have a new object in the admin with an attached excel file. I'm trying something like this

```
def test(request):
    exported_ingredients = export(request, app_name='ingredients', model_name='ingredient')
    new_export = IngredientExportItem(file_name="x", slug="x", file=exported_ingredients)
    new_export.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

I keep getting this error though: `'HttpResponse' object has no attribute '_committed'`

Doesn't seem to like the object I'm setting to 'file' property(file is a fileupload field). If I just return the object then my browser downloads the file correctly so the file is OK.

Comment: Could you post full traceback?

Comment: Here is the full traceback http://dpaste.com/689377/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your response is not a django file object, it's a django `HttpResponse` object.

Check out [ContentFile](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/file/#the-contentfile-class) if you want to create a django file object from a string.

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

def test(request):
    http_response = export(request, app_name='ingredients', model_name='ingredient')
    file_ = ContentFile(http_response.content)
    file_.name = http_response['Content-Disposition'].split('=')[-1] 

    new_export = IngredientExportItem(file_name="x", slug="x", file=file_)
    new_export.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Comment: Thanks Yuji! I got confused because the object was downloading correctly but now I see you need to convert it to the correct type to save it.

Comment: @mongoose_za, NP - that's the browser interpreting that it's a download based on the `Content-Disposition` and other header.